# trouble with \date{} respecting value passed?

Tags: class-options, date

I've been using a uni template suite (`.tex`, `.cls` and `.bib`) for my thesis, and just noticed today that the date value specified in my main `.tex` this way:

```
\date{09/14/2016}
```

magically becomes today's date, regardless the value passed in.

There's a validation in the `.cls` like this:

```
\def\@date{??/??/??\ClassError{orsay-memoire}{No defense date given}
```

Since I'm extremely new to LaTeX this made me suspicious, so I fruitlessly tried all sorts of date formats, including simply `\date{01/01/01}`. It still says today's the day.

The class presents the date in the document this way: `Presented \@date{} before the Committee`

No packages mentioning dates are loaded.

Comment: the standard latex `\date` command just defines `\@date` to be the supplied string, so if that is not happening, either your value of `\date` isn't executed or something has redefined `\date` impossible to guess given the above information.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I'll break it down a little and try to post a MWE.

Comment: Found my error -- I'd copy/pasted in a glossary content table which contained ```\date{\today}```, then somehow I missed it in my first search for ```\date```. Enjoying LaTeX, comfort is a long way off.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was due to a copy-and-paste of superfluous information that overwrote the user input.

Comment: While I agree that including two conflicting inputs is a beginner error, I do wish finding my - and others' - blunders was simpler. I might have thought a compiler would cough up a warning on such conflicts. (Thank you for explaining your vote, regardless.)

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling through posts of users with similar setups and [symptoms](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=16713), turns out my issue was simply that I'd cut/pasted this along with a new glossary below my intro:

```
\input{glossary}
\makeglossaries
\date{\today}
\newpage
```

Obviously this `\date{\today}` overruled my intended `\date{18/09/2016}`, then I somehow missed it while debugging.